# Need replacement handle for shower

Tags: shower

Does anyone know what brand this is and how I can replace the handle/lever? The water turns on by pushing up and then side to side for temperature adjustment. Thanks[image]

Comment: There are markings that I can not read due low resolution of the photo. Try to read them

Comment: Smells like a Delta from not very much detail.